# Construct a prime using $[2, 2, 2, ...., 3]$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, summation, prime-numbers

Is there a generalized method to constructing primes through sums using the set $[2, 2, 2, ..., 3]$ given its elements are $n$- many 2s and a 3. This question obviously requires knowledge on differences between the primes you are constructing, and as they aren't constant throughout the natural numbers, I wonder specifically if there is a way of constructing a prime $p$ such that $n < p < 2n$. An example would be:
$$\text{Let}\,\,\,n = 10$$
Let's consider constructing the prime number '19'. We have the set $[2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3]$ and from the set we use $2+2+2+2+2+2+2+2+3 = 19$.
I would appreciate it if anyone could share any facts, results, theorems,... thank you

Comment: I mean, you can get all primes less than or equal to $3+2n.$ You might have to exclude $2$ and $3$ if you don't allow a "sum" to be a sum of one element.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thats the obvious one. But what about primes of the form $3+3n$? or $3+5n$?...

Comment: If there ar only $n$ 2s, you can't get a sum higher than $3+2n.$ $5+2n$ is not a "form," it is a constant, because $n$ is a constant. (Like your example, $n=10.$) A prime of the form $5+2k$ can be written in this form if $0\leq k\leq n-1$

Comment: Actually, you can obtain every  positive integer up to the maximal sum $2n+3$ with only two exceptions: $1$ and $2n+2$.

Comment: What do you mean with "constructing primes" in this context ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if my answer is specifically what you are looking for. First you must know that there are infinitely many prime numbers of the form $2n+3$.

Now, a simple way to generate (build) primes within this arithmetic progression is by means of a computer, for example this code written in SageMath:

```
sage: L = (2*n+3 for n in range(1000))
sage: [a for a in L if a.is_prime()]
```

Thus, for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ in $[0,1000]$ we obtain the following primes:

[3,
5,
7,
11,
13,
17,
19,
23,
29,
31,
37,
41,
43,
47,
53,
59,
61,
67,
71,
73,
79,
83,
89,
97,
101,
103,
107,
109,
113,
127,
131,
137,
139,
149,
151,
157,
163,
167,
173,
179,
181,
191,
193,
197,
199,
211,
223,
227,
229,
233,
239,
241,
251,
257,
263,
269,
271,
277,
281,
283,
293,
307,
311,
313,
317,
331,
337,
347,
349,
353,
359,
367,
373,
379,
383,
389,
397,
401,
409,
419,
421,
431,
433,
439,
443,
449,
457,
461,
463,
467,
479,
487,
491,
499,
503,
509,
521,
523,
541,
547,
557,
563,
569,
571,
577,
587,
593,
599,
601,
607,
613,
617,
619,
631,
641,
643,
647,
653,
659,
661,
673,
677,
683,
691,
701,
709,
719,
727,
733,
739,
743,
751,
757,
761,
769,
773,
787,
797,
809,
811,
821,
823,
827,
829,
839,
853,
857,
859,
863,
877,
881,
883,
887,
907,
911,
919,
929,
937,
941,
947,
953,
967,
971,
977,
983,
991,
997,
1009,
1013,
1019,
1021,
1031,
1033,
1039,
1049,
1051,
1061,
1063,
1069,
1087,
1091,
1093,
1097,
1103,
1109,
1117,
1123,
1129,
1151,
1153,
1163,
1171,
1181,
1187,
1193,
1201,
1213,
1217,
1223,
1229,
1231,
1237,
1249,
1259,
1277,
1279,
1283,
1289,
1291,
1297,
1301,
1303,
1307,
1319,
1321,
1327,
1361,
1367,
1373,
1381,
1399,
1409,
1423,
1427,
1429,
1433,
1439,
1447,
1451,
1453,
1459,
1471,
1481,
1483,
1487,
1489,
1493,
1499,
1511,
1523,
1531,
1543,
1549,
1553,
1559,
1567,
1571,
1579,
1583,
1597,
1601,
1607,
1609,
1613,
1619,
1621,
1627,
1637,
1657,
1663,
1667,
1669,
1693,
1697,
1699,
1709,
1721,
1723,
1733,
1741,
1747,
1753,
1759,
1777,
1783,
1787,
1789,
1801,
1811,
1823,
1831,
1847,
1861,
1867,
1871,
1873,
1877,
1879,
1889,
1901,
1907,
1913,
1931,
1933,
1949,
1951,
1973,
1979,
1987,
1993,
1997,
1999]

Comment: _All_ odd primes are of the form $2n+3$. since that describes all the odd integers greater than $1$.

Comment: that's right, maybe I didn't understand the question properly

Comment: I think you did understand what the OP was asking for, but you didn't see that it was not a good question.

Comment: I was planning to delete my answer, but hopefully you can use the code to generate primes in other arithmetic progressions.

Answer (score 0):

***All*** odd primes are of the form $2n+3$, since
that describes all the odd integers greater than $1$.

[Bertrand's postulate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate) (which is a theorem) says that there is always a prime between $n$ and $2n$.